# Why does the angle decrease as height increases in bi-level projectiles?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, projectile

Not taking air resistance into account. 
I know that the optimal angle for biggest range on a uni-level projectile is 45 degrees. I also know at, as the starting height of the projectile increases the time it is in the air and the range is increased. But why does the optimal angle decrease as the starting height of the projectile is increased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we divide the trajectory into two parts:

[image: Trajectory]

So $s_1$ is the distance travelled by the time the projectile returns to its initial height, and $s_2$ is the extra distance travelled as the projectile moves below its initial height. The distance $s_1$ is given by the usual formula:

$$ s_1 = \frac{v^2}{g}\sin2\theta $$

Deriving the expression for $s_2$ is tedious but straightforward. If you graph $s_1$ and $s_2$ as a function of the initial angle it looks like (this particular calculation used $v = 10$m/s and $h = 10$m):

[image: Trajectory]

As you'd expect the red line, showing $s_1$, peaks at $\theta = \pi/4$. However the green line, showing $s_2$, increases smoothly with $\theta$.

Now this is how we show the total distance $s = s_1 + s_2$ peaks at increased angle without having to do an explicit calculation. The gradient of the blue line will be:

$$ \frac{ds}{d\theta} = \frac{d(s_1 + s_2)}{d\theta} = \frac{ds_1}{d\theta} + \frac{ds_2}{d\theta} \tag{1}$$

If we consider the gradient at $\theta = \pi/4$ we know that at this angle $ds_1/d\theta = 0$ because $s_1$ is a maximum at $\theta = \pi/4$. So equation (1) gives us:

$$ \frac{ds}{d\theta}(\pi/4) = \frac{ds_2}{d\theta}(\pi/4) $$

And it's obvious from the diagram that $ds_2/d\theta(\pi/4) > 0$ and that means at $\theta = \pi/4$ we have $ds/d\theta \gt 0$ i.e. the total range is still increasing. Therefore the total range $s$ must peak at an angle greater than $\theta = \pi/4$.

Answer (score 0):

The reason 45 degrees is optimal in idealized solution is because the distance is the horizontal component of muzzle velocity multiplied by flight time. And since the projectile goes up and comes down as long, the time is simply two times the vertical component divided by gravity. So distance is proportional to vertical and horizontal components multiplied with each other. This is largest when the components are equal, which happen when the angle is 45 degrees.

If the starting height is higher the time up and the time down are no longer equal. This is basically equivalent of getting free vertical velocity and horizontal velocity needs now be equal to the vertical component plus this "free velocity" for optimal distance. This makes horizontal component larger than the vertical, which equals smaller angle.

Note that this is a lame attempt to explain this without any math or formula. So it might be wrong. Still thought it wortwhile as the basic principle should be right.